# Trying to set up cron job

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, cron

I want to run cron job every night at 1am and after that every 3 hours from morning 10am-6pm only.

> 0 1,10-18/3 * * *

Is this the correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would simple spell out the hours rather than using the step.  Even though your syntax seems correct `10-18/3` looks awkward to me.

```
0 1,10,13,16 * * * command
```

Immediately makes clear what you intend. (And notice how every three hours between 10AM And 6PM is only ten AM, one and four PM.)

Comment: yeah, makes more sense.